# Finding double bookings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables which when linked by a booking ID from table 1 and ID from table 2

Therefore

```
Table 1 contains BookingID, MemberID, BookedDate.
Table 2 contains ID, StartDateTime, EndDatetime
```

Im trying to flag double bookings where the same member id has booked twice within a time frame (StartDateTime and EndDateTime). Then remove the booking that has the latest BookedDate.

Can someone help me with a sql script for this?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance

Ian

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain why you are using an unsupported commercial database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the member id from the first table and then you are just looking for overlaps:

```
with t as (
      select t2.*, t1.memberid
      from table2 t2 join
           table1 t1
           on t2.id = t1.bookid
     )
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.memberid = t.memberid and
                    t2.id <> t.id and
                    t2.startdate < t.enddate and
                    t2.enddate > t.startdate
             );
```

Comment: HI Gordon, your theory is correct, however the script you have provided doesnt seem to be showing that as im getting members showing that have say 4 bookings but these are spread over 4 days so the bookings themselves are not overlapping?

Comment: @IanHutchisoni . .  . I think the most consistent mistake I make is leaving out the comparison to the current row in this type of logic.  I just fixed the query.